# Display a glTF/glb model with three.js in hugo

Tags: html, three.js, hugo

I am using hugo with the coder theme to make a personal website. i want to display a glTF/glb model as the avatar on the home page. i have managed to write a index.html file, where i can display a glTF/glb model (without hugo).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load GLTF Model with Three.js</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      .avatar { width: 400px; height: 400px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      
      const avatar = document.querySelector('.avatar');
      const width = avatar.offsetWidth;
      const height = avatar.offsetHeight;
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      
      avatar.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
      let model;
      loader.load(
        'model.glb',
        function (gltf) {
          model = gltf.scene;
          scene.add(model);
        },
        function (xhr) {
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log('An error happened', error);
        }
      );

      camera.position.z = 1;

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        if (model) {
          model.rotation.y += 0.005;
        }
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then i thought, that i just copy the partial layout `avatar.html` from the theme and paste the code from the file above in it. My `avatar_model.html`looks like this.

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script>
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  
  const avatar = document.querySelector('.avatar');
  const width = avatar.offsetWidth;
  const height = avatar.offsetHeight;
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
  avatar.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  let model;
  loader.load(
    'static/images/avatar_model.glb',
    function (gltf) {
      model = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(model);
    },
    function (xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('An error happened', error);
    }
  );

  camera.position.z = 1;

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if (model) {
      model.rotation.y += 0.005;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();
</script>
```

but this won't work. i become an error in the console of the browser: `XHRGEThttp://localhost:1313/static/images/avatar_model.glb [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]` but the path to the model is correct i have it saved in the directory `static/images`.

can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The path should be:

`http://localhost:1313/images/avatar_model.glb`

... as the static is not a folder in your output (you can check that with the 'hugo' command).